# Foreach query insert in multiple rows PHP not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I Googled and tested but can not get my below php script to insert into my MySQL database. When I run the query directly in my mysql management tool the INSERT works. I want to INSERT the query into multiple rows in the table `task_in`.

I tested my database/table connection and it is ok, so can someone please explain why my php script do not insert any data in my database table `task_in`?

**PHP SCRIPT:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['tasks'])) {
    $tasks = $_POST['tasks'];
    foreach ($tasks as $task_list_id) {
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO task_in (task_list_id, customer_id, user_id, created_at) 
            VALUES ('$task_list_id', '1', '1', NOW())");
    print_r($task_list_id);
    }
}
?>
```

**Part of my form:**

```
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tasks[][task_list_id]" value=<?php echo($key[0]);?>></td>
<td><input type="checkbox" name="tasks[][task_list_id]" value=<?php echo($key[1]);?>></td> </tr>
    <td>Nav.rep For</td>
```

**The print_r in the foreach loop returns this:**

```
Array
(
    [task_list_id] => 1
)
Array
(
    [task_list_id] => 2
)
Array
(
    [task_list_id] => 8
)
```

**My table task_in looks like this:**

```
CREATE TABLE `task_in` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `task_id_unique` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `task_list_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `taskListId` (`task_list_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `taskListId` FOREIGN KEY (`task_list_id`) REFERENCES `task_list` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=50 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Ps. I am fully aware of sql injections in my above code + PDO and Mysqli and it will be changed asap. So please do not comment on this.

---

**UPDATE SOLVED.**

@axiac suggestions works and also as commented by @fejese, my table which have a foreign key **taks_list_id** was expecting **INT** and got a string, and therefore it returned the following sql error:
 
**Invalid query: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`workcard`.`task_in`, CONSTRAINT `taskListId` FOREIGN KEY (`task_list_id`) REFERENCES `task_list` (`id`))**

I added the implode function to my php script and this php script solved the insert issue:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['tasks'])) {
    $tasks = $_POST['tasks'];
    foreach ($tasks as $task_list_id) {
        $values = implode('""', $task_list_id);
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO task_in (task_list_id, customer_id, user_id, created_at) 
            VALUES ('$values', '1', '1', NOW())");
    }
    if (!$sql) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you all for your suggestion and comments.

Comment: Although you should include the error message reported by `mysql_error` and for starters do not use the `mysql_*` functions at all, I'm guessing you have an SQL error because of `task_id_unique` int(11) NOT NULL` not being inserted with your query

Comment: '$task_list_id' change to '".$task_list_id."'

Comment: To debug this properly you need to echo out the `$sql` variable from within the `foreach` loop. To see exactly what is being generated as the query statement.

Comment: ... @fejese you are right. See my update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `$task_list_id` is an array and it should probably be an integer. Just change the HTML to look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tasks[]" ...>
```

and that will fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I think $task_list_id should be $task_list_id['task_list_id'] in VALUES section of query as it must not be an array.